# passport authentication doesn't work with multer in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, multer

I am trying to upload an image using multer. However, I want to authenticate the user before they can upload an image. My code is below and the passport.authenticate does't work. I can upload without loggin in.

```
const router = express.Router();
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

  router.route("/", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }))
  .post(
    upload.single("image"),
    (req, res, next) => {.....})
```

However, the authentication works in this way, but I cannot use multer.

```
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {...})
```

Comment: Are you providing an Authorization header in your POST? What behavior are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Yes, I am. The authentication works, but not when I use multer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

router.route() only accept 1st path parameter, so 2nd parameter(passport.authenticate()) was ignored silently. 
You can verify.

```
router.route("/", function(req,res,next){console.log('in 2nd param');next()})
.post()
```

I think you can use multer like below.

```
router.post("/",
            passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
            upload.single("image"),
            (req, res) => {...})
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I don't know why I couldn't figure that out. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use multer inside your post route this way you can authenticate your router

```
router.post(‘/‘, passport , (req, res) =>{

})
```